# Weird x/y axis labels in ggplot 2 - plotting calendary weeks

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

my table looks like this:

```
Article     1      2      3     ....
P1          100    3000   300
P2          0      7000   200   .....
...
```

So there are Articles and Calendary weeks (until 53).

I want to plot the CW on the x axis, the value on the y axis and for every Article one line.

My code:

```
library(readxl)##data
istvolumen_data <- read_excel("~/Dropbox/5. Semester/WI3/KOMPLETT.xlsx", sheet = "Programmplanung", range = "B41:BC49")


library(reshape2) ##melting
dat_m <- melt(istvolumen_data, id.vars = "Artikel", 
              measure.vars = grep("^", names(istvolumen_data), value = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)##plotting
ggplot(dat_m, aes(y = value, x = variable, colour = as.factor(Artikel))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Artikel)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 300))
```

.

But this gives my some weird plot:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks A LOT for the help. I'm new to ggplot2 and R!

EDIT: Here the respond to MKRS question ...

[dput used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xko9i.png)

...and a better visualization of my problem with the y axis:

[y-axis problematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzu3H.png)

Comment: i'm wondering about the y axis labels AND that there is the "Artikel" as a tick in the x axis.

Comment: Please use `dput` and share data of `istvolumen_data`

Comment: Can you check `class(dat_m[["value"]])` ? My guess that it is not numeric, but rather a factor or a string.

Comment: its a character!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, converted it now to numeric. seems to work. i appreciate your effort.